# Jenkins slave terminates during build execution

Tags: windows, java, jenkins

I have an issue with Jenkins slave getting terminated during build execution.

- OS: windows 2012 R2 (both Master and Slave)
- Java: 1.8.0_211 (both Mater and Salve)
- Jenkins Version: 2.176.2Slave
- Launch Method: Java Web start, JNLP(Launch by connecting it to the Master)

Issue: I have a project in Jenkins which fails mainly because the slave terminates after 'Starting ServiceWrapper in the CLI mode' during execution. Finds a child process `conhost.exe` and failed due to Killing as fallback.

This is happening only for a project/ pipeline, where I have python script which pings an internal URL (https://URL/ping), invokes the network emulator tool installed, adjust the network latency and also write to a file/ push to ELK. I have an internet proxy set up using .pac file.

It completes all the steps in project, at the end the slave terminates, marking the build as failure.

Note: We also have another old version of Jenkins 2.76 installed where the same project/ pipeline works with out any issue. Now we want to upgrade to latest Jenkins we are seeing issue with slave getting terminated. I now have to close the network emulator tool every time and restart the Jenkins service to bring it back online.

Error as observed in Jenkins-slave.wrapper.log:

```
2019-07-24 03:51:59,751 INFO  - Stopping jenkinsslave-e__jenkins
2019-07-24 03:51:59,751 DEBUG - ProcessKill 6872
2019-07-24 03:51:59,860 INFO  - Found child process: 6408 Name: conhost.exe
2019-07-24 03:51:59,892 INFO  - Stopping process 6408
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 INFO  - Send SIGINT 6408
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 WARN  - SIGINT to 6408 failed - Killing as fallback
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 INFO  - Stopping process 6872
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 INFO  - Send SIGINT 6872
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 WARN  - SIGINT to 6872 failed - Killing as fallback
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 INFO  - Finished jenkinsslave-e__jenkins
2019-07-24 03:51:59,907 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
```

Error as observed in jenkins-slave.error.log:

```
Jul 24, 2019 3:57:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener statusJul 
24, 2019 3:57:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener statusINFO: Terminated
Jul 24, 2019 3:57:23 AM hudson.util.ProcessTree getWARNING: Error while determining if vetoers existhudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException 
at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:340) at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:1040) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:209) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:172) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer.access$1800(BIONetworkLayer.java:48) 
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader.run(BIONetworkLayer.java:264) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection to jenkinsmater/IP address:33131 
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743) 
at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:202) at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:286) 
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.fetch3(Unknown Source) 
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:209) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:383) at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:307) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:383) at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:307) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:383) at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:307) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
at hudson.util.ProcessTree.get(ProcessTree.java:415) 
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1103) at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1094) 
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212) 
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54) at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369) 
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ... 4 moreCaused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException ... 7 more
Jul 24, 2019 3:57:23 AM hudson.util.ProcessTree getWARNING: Failed to load winp. Reverting to the defaultjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/ProcessTree$WindowsOSProcessException 
at hudson.util.ProcessTree.get(ProcessTree.java:430) 
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1103) at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1094) 
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212) 
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54) at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369) 
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.ProcessTree$WindowsOSProcessException at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:171) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 12 more
Jul 24, 2019 3:57:23 AM hudson.remoting.Request$2 runINFO: Failed to send back a reply to the request hudson.remoting.Request$2@626d990c: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@4d834d1e:JNLP4-connect connection to jenkinsmaster/IP Address:33131": channel is already closed

Jul 24, 2019 3:57:33 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener statusINFO: Performing onReconnect operation.
```

Can someone please help with this issue?